# Broadcasting and Fetch Data On UART

Tags: collision, avr, uart, atmega, rs485

I have a computer (that use as server) and several board with `Atmega` microcontroller Something like:

[image: computer and board]

The computer connect to board on `UART` & `RS485` (with a `USB` to `RS485` converter)(I have limitation that lead to I **could not use ModBus**). I want to **broadcast a message** from server over bus and fetch the ID from of each board (Board ID is **4 digit**).

When the boards receive broadcast message and try to send their own ID and the server receive some fake ID and I think it related to Collisions problem when all boards want  to send data in *one time*.

After I search about this problem found a way that put a constant in each board that save a special delay for send data and when board receive broadcast message send ID with that delay...in this way it work fine and I dont see the Collisions but have some problem:

1. May be the delay number of 2 board be same.
2. Good way for small count of board.
3. Extra process when want to install board on bus.

Anybody know with this problem and could help me how to solve this problem with *better solution*?

Comment: Having multiple stations on a shared bus simultaneously answer to broadcasts is a bad idea. Do you have some logic in the client boards that tries to detect whether the bus is currently occupied before they try to access it for an answer (That would be the "CSMA" part of CSMA/CD)

Comment: *"...and the server receive some fake ID"* -- Sounds like you need to implement a better message integrity check.  *"But in totally it work fine"* -- Then you have low expectations, and  you should be done, right?

Comment: @sawdust _and the server receive some fake ID_ : I find error in find fake ID, But my problem is **How to prevent client to send fake ID**..._But in totally it work fine_ yes it work but have the problem that i say in question.. the main problem is _May be the delay number of 2 board be same._ and it lead to Collisions again...

Comment: *" I find error in find fake ID"* -- Instead of *"finding fake ID"*, you should be able to detect any type of message collisions, e.g. by using a message validation such as CRC.  *"in totally it work fine_ yes it work but ..."* -- You fail to realize that you're contradicting yourself.  Something *"totally works"*, or it doesn't; there are no buts.   *"Board ID is 4 digit"* -- Are there 10,000 possible boards on one RS-485 line?  Why aren't you using the Modbus slave ID, which is only 8 bits?   It's starting to seem like that you haven't properly layered your protocol.

Comment: About _finding fake ID_ I think its better find a collisions in sending ID from board rather than _find fake ID in server_ even a _validation such as CRC_ may could find fake ID from in Server. I replace this part _"totally works"_ with "in this way it work fine and I dont see the Collisions but have some **problem**:"  About _Why aren't you using the Modbus slave ID_ I have limitation in board that could not use that way. _It's starting to seem like that you haven't properly layered your protocol_ I send data over UART protocol byte by byte ...Continue on ext comment

Comment: I dont need requirement to use special protocol while want to send some byte by byte. I think collisions not related to protocol.

Comment: *"I have limitation to use ModBus"* -- But you seem to make no effort to be Modbus compliant.  See http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1.pdf for mandatory requirements that you're not implementing.  You also seem to not understand the concept of message validation and protocol layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mentioning Modbus in your question although some of your other stated facts seem to deviate from there (like 4-digit device numbers, and Modbus only has 1-255). Also, Modbus **does not** support responses to broadcast messages. I thus doubt a bit you are actually using Modbus.

A scheme you could use (and that is classically used in MA networks) would be:

1. Once a broadcast is received, have the clients scan the bus for responses for a time frame based on its station ID. If your client can see one, have it wait a minimum bus time (the time a module needs to answer your broadcast message based on current bus timing + the round trip for the master acknowledging the broadcast answer) plus an additional time based on its module ID, then go back to (1)
2. If a client sees the bus unoccupied for the specified time, send back a broadcast answer.
3. Have the master acknowledge the broadcast response from this client with the shortest possible message.
4. If a client that has sent a broadcast response does not receive a proper ack, go back to (1)

This is not 100% secure and absolutely not according to the Modbus specification, but could work.

```
* is a transmission, - is a "wait"

****  (Bus master broadcast)

    --------- station 100 waits 100ms
    ------------------ station 200 waits 200ms
             **** Station 100 sends broadcast response
                ------------------ station 200 sees bus active and waits another 200ms
                 *** master acknowledges broadcast response of 100
                    ------------------ station 200 sees bus active again and waits 200ms from last seen activity
                                      **** Station 200 has seen bus quiet for 200ms and sends broadcast response
                                          *** master acks brc response of 200
```

This can take quite a bit of time and needs the waiting times finely adjusted against the transmission time of broadcast responses and response acks, but can work, and actually is implemented that way in a lot of CSMA/CD networks.

Comment: Oh sorry i think I could not explain my question correctly in modbus section...i could not use modbus, as i say in question i use rs485.

Comment: Modbus *is* physically RS-485.

Comment: Yes but use 2 max485,  but i use 1 max485 ic for commnicuation

Comment: You say _If your client can see one.._  ok, but how a board find other board behind? By a special message? This message either have question problem

Comment: That means after receiving a broadcast, the client has to check the bus for a specific and unique between all stations amount of time whether someone else answers. Only after that specific time it may answer in order not to produce a collision. Let's say station 100 waits for 100ms for an unoccupied bus, station 200 waits 200ms - This ensures that station 100 will start transmitting, and station 200 will not (because it "can see" 100's transmission during its own wait time) and will thus not cause a collision.

Comment: Instead of using the station #, a random wait time (with significantly higher chance of duplicates and thus collisions) can be used. Try to draw a timing diagram of all stations, that helps.

Comment: Actually did that for you in above answer

Comment: Good guide torfo  i try to implement that

Comment: Note the times I used are arbitrary examples - they need to be adjusted for your specific situation. And if you liked the answer, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably take longer, but here is another way to do it.  First, design your protocol so that each command contains (or an can contain) an ID, and boards only respond to commands for their ID.  Then, on your host, you would iterate through each of the possible IDs and send a simple command to each of them.  If you get a response, you know there is a board with that ID.  If you don't get a response after some period of time, you know there is no board there.

Comment: But the device have randome ID..do you know a special framework that design a protokol for this reson?

Comment: You say in your answer that i could send command by id of a board..but i dont know they ID anyway..thay have an ID that random generated and store in that..your approch is OK when i have ID list of board...onother thing is i want to **broadcast** message to board..not unicast

Comment: My answer explained that you would try each of the possible IDs.  So if you know IDs will always be between 0 and 127, you try 0, then you try 1, then you try 2, etc.  So you don't have to know the IDs ahead of time.  Your desire to broadcast something is not so important; the main issue is that you want to figure out what IDs the boards have and you are trying to find a solution to that problem.  After the system figures out the IDs, it could broadcast or do whatever kind of protocol you want.

Comment: I edit my question...as you see in the picture in question the device ID is 4 digit..and its too long period to find a 4 digit ID _one by one_. If a find a way to fetch  device list first, your approach is work fine